# VB.NET - Creating objects on every loop

Tags: vb.net

Please take a look at the code below:

```
    Public Sub MassDelete()
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
        Dim objCon As SqlConnection
        Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
        Try
            Dim _ConString As String = "Data Source=IANSCOMPUTER;Initial Catalog=Test5;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
            objCon = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
            Using objCon
                    objCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE StartDate <= dateadd(-6,year," & Now & ")")
                objCommand.Connection = objCon
                Using objCommand
                    objCon.Open()
                    objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader
                    Do While objDR.Read
                        'Send ID over web service
                        'Send email to person
                        'Add log entry to log file
                    Loop
                    objDR.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally

        End Try
```

I see lots of code like this from a previous developer i.e. one function that loops through a table e.g. person, vehicle, account etc and performs actions on thousands or in some cases millions of records.  In the case of the above, persons are deleted six years after the start date.  There are three actions for every iteration of the while loop i.e. send id over web service, send email to person and add log entry to log file.  I am trying to refactor this code as I continue the development of the system in question.

I believe that there should be different classes for Email, WebService and Log and instead of doing all the work in the MassDelete function; the work will be spread out among the classes e.g. the email will be sent from the Email class.  Is there any limitations of creating objects for WebService, Email and Log for every iteration of the loop and using their instance variables (there could be a million records to loop around in Person)?

Comment: FWIW: use [`Using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx). One reason to keep it dispatched from a single location (even if "the sending code" is located in a different class) is that a Transaction *can* be utilized. And no, object creation is cheap. However, does the "send email" object *really need* to be a new instance or does it just provide a service like `SendEmail(address,subject,message)`? In this case it would make no sense to make it an `EmailBoundToAnAddress` class. Now the WebService/Logging code *are* bound to something - but not the thing that changes each loop.

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the question with Using statements.  I don't understand the remainder of your last comment.  Could you clarify or post an answer?

Comment: Which part? (I am a habitual editor.)

Comment: @pst, thanks.  You edited the comment just before I submitted my previous comment.  Are you saying that you would not create separate objects?  The reason I want to do this is for reuseability i.e. send email can be found in multiple 'Delete' methods e.g. when a person, account, vehicle etc is deleted.  Instead of having an email in each function, the logic should be in one place.

Comment: If you really think to refactor then think to make your `send id to webservice, send email to person, add log entry` operations able to work on List(of Person) instead of work on a single person at time

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, but you only need to create the "service" instance once per scope - not once per loop.

Comment: And of course classes are fine, just try to make static methods when it makes sense (for example an EMail.SendMail(List(Of Person)) ans so on

Comment: @Steve That throws off numbers for logs, and e-mails only work batched if using CC/BCC. It might be beneficial for the WS, if the WS understands a batch operation itself. It also makes it hard to be able to stop "correctly" on an Exception or other failure .. but Message Queues may be more appropriate to begin with.

Comment: @pst, I see.  Create one person object before control is passed to the while loop and then use the one person object in the while loop.

Comment: @pst, could you post an answer so that I can give some credit?

Comment: @w0051977 No, no. Each loop has a *different* Person (presumably this is derived from each record) but uses the *same* "services" - email,  sending WS, logging. So it might be: `Person p = ReadFromRecord(r); emailService.SendMail(person.EmailAddress, "SUBJ: Deleting", "It's all gone!!!")` - That's assuming the email is sent to the "target", and not a sysadmin or other log, of course. The `emailService` is only created once (and likewise for the WS/Log, the Log likely comes from a higher context too).

Comment: @pst, the classes for Log, WebService and Email would contain instance variables that would be populated on every loop.

Comment: @w0051977 Don't make them instance variables. They are not part of the service - but only data fed in when making a particular service call. The service is not "bound" to a Person, but provides a particular service.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you define "part of" the service? Sender and receiver are part of the email class in my view.

Comment: @w0051977 If you really want to do that, make it so. However, I have *never* found that to work out well. Keep in mind these are *services* and not *data objects*.

Comment: Umm... your program is practically begging to get hacked. This method is okay, but it strongly hints that you're using string concatenation to substitute data into your sql queries elsewhere in the program, and that leaves you open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, I never use string concatenation in queries.  I always use parameterised queries.

Comment: Good... then fix this one.

Comment: And while we're at it, you'll get slightly better performance by doing the date calculation on the client instead the database server: `WHERE StartDate <= @MinDate` ... `objCommand.Parameters("@MinDate").Value = Now.AddYears(-6)` The difference probably won't be noticeable, but it can be dramatic: sometimes the function use in the WHERE clause can prevent good index use.

Comment: It seems a bit cruel w.r.t timeouts for the database connection if the three actions take some time (particularly the send email) - could you read all the data from the database in one go and then act on the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While object creation is *cheap* - that is, creating new objects per loop will have no overall performance impact (dependent upon how much work the constructor does) - new objects should only be done when it is semantically correct/meaningful to do so.

In this case I am advocating keeping a *service* separate from the *data* (e.g. Person record) which is merely passed into particular service calls. I don't actually know VB.NET (I use C#) so adjust the syntax as required.

```
' Note that the services are bound to some things - but NOT people
' I recommend using DI/IoC (Dependency Injection)
' Also the Logger is generally a larger application-wide service
Var mailer = New EmailService(SMTPServerString, SMTPTimeout)
Var ws = New WebService(WSEndpoint)
Var log = New LoggerService()
Var objCon = OpenConnection()

Using objCon
    Var objCommand = objCon.CreateCommand(..);
    Using objCommand
        Var objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader
        Do While objDR.Read
            ' Person different per loop
            Var person = New Person(objDR) 
            ' But services are the same and are not "bound" to a person
            ws.RecordDelete(person.Id)
            mailer.Send(person.Email, Subject, Message)
            log.Log(Log.Information, "Deleted person: " & person.Id)
        Loop
    End Using
End Using
```

Of course, this code still isn't very fault tolerant or distributable. Message Queues (e.g AMPQ) might be worth looking into ..

Comment: Thanks +1.  I see that mailer and ws contain shared (static) functions i.e. Send and RecordDelete respectively.  Is there any technical reason not to use instance variables e.g. for the .SEND parameters i.e. person.Email, Subject and Message

Comment: @w0051977 **No static functions** - instance methods :D And yes, because that munges a *service* with a domain entity (*data*). By keeping the services separate they are easily re-usable without any coupling and by keeping the *data* out of the service we can make it easy for IoC/DI as well (which is a big win).

Comment: yes please disregard the first part of my previous comment.  Is there any technical reason not to use instance variables e.g. for the .SEND parameters i.e. person.Email, Subject and Message

Comment: @w0051977 Consider going to a Post Office - do you `New PostOffice(Me, Recipient).SendParcel(Parcel)` or do you `LocalPostOffice.SendParcel(Me, Recipient, Parcel)`? Or even "fluent" like `LocalPostOffice.From(Me).To(Recpient).Send(Parcel)` - but even in this case it's still the *same* Post Office or "service".

Comment: Your last comment was very helpful.  Finally, is there a scenario where you would New PostOffice(Me, Recipient).SendParcel(Parcel) during a batch processing operation like the example in my original post?

Comment: @w0051977 No, there is not (that I can think of now). I might aggregate *data* to pass to a service, however. `SendAllMail(Me, Letters)` where Letters is a List<Letter> and a Letter has an Address (Recipient) and Contents. The service can then do what it needs (or doesn't need to) do on the entire (local) dataset. The data can be composed as required and (with very rare exceptions) should be kept separate from services - services use (and provide) data.

Comment: How do you define "part of" the service as described in one of your commentS?

Comment: You said "part of" in your second to last comment under my original post.

Comment: @w0051977 The *data* (Sender, Recipient, Parcel) is not part of the *service* (Post Office).

Comment: On that basis: couldn't you argue that: name, age and address are not instance variables of the person class because they are data? Every person class I have looked at online today has them as instance variables.

Comment: @w0051977 A person is not a service - in this case it is data about something (or a DTO/DO - Domain [Transfer] Object) that represents a *collection of data* about a particular record. However, if you didn't want a person class, then the database record could be used directly. (I use LINQ2SQL - but there are many alternatives out there to automatically map records - and prefer not to touch raw datareaders/commands.)

Comment: @w0051977 In a *rich* object graph (e.g. the SharePoint Object Model) one might have a person "know" how to do things itself, but there is no use/need/benefit for simple *data* objects as in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I wish I could upvote this answer more than once as you have answered more than one question here.

Comment: if you have time to answer my other question here then please do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700960/data-access-layer-utility-classes-and-data-transfer-objects