# Data Access Layer - Utility classes and data transfer objects

Tags: vb.net

I have a book, which talks about design patterns and the use of layers in particular i.e. presentation layer, business logic layer and data access layer.

I now understand the concept of a utility class and a data transfer object.  However, all of the examples and information in the book talk about how they apply to the business logic layer.

I assume that they also apply to the data logic layer as well or is there another design pattern that I am unaware of?

This question follows on from a question I asked yesterday, here: [VB.NET - Creating objects on every loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692912/vb-net-creating-objects-on-every-loop).

I will post some code to clarify what I am asking if required, though this is more of a conceptual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utility classes and DTOs are equally at home in the data and presentation layers. I often use DTOs defined in the data layer to pass data "up" to the business layer.

Comment: Thanks. +1. Therefore if you have separate dlls for the bll and dal (tiers), then the dto's will have to go in a dll of their own?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I usually have a "Common" DLL that the other layers have reference to. My DTOs live there.

Comment: Do you use interfaces when calling DAL functions from the BLL? If so then do you put these interfaces in the DTO DLL?

Comment: Oh, I remember you from the "Interfaces and Hungarian Notation" thread! Still hung up on Interfaces? LOL :-)  I use interfaces, but they stay in the same assembly as their derived classes. I have interfaces in the Common layer, but they are interfaces for the "Common" stuff.

Comment: Yes, it still hasn't clicked yet. I assume that you would not use interfaces for bll to bll calls? Thanks.

Comment: Normally not.  I don't want to confuse you, but I may use them for a BLL to BLL call if I'm using a Factory Pattern. Example, `Dim obj as IWidget = WidgetFactory.CreateWidget()`. This is all within the BLL.

Comment: Finally, I assume that bll to dll calls would use interfaces? Do you ever use instance variables in the dal? I do.

Comment: In your answer you say: "equally at home in the data and presentation layers". I assume you mean: equally at home in the bll and dal?

Comment: No, I meant presentation: You said you only saw them used in the BLL, I was pointing out that they can be anywhere.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you use a framework like hibernate or do you write all the data access code yourself (last question)?

Comment: Can you answer the question in my last comment?